# OxyPlot get clicked point

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, oxyplot

I am trying to plot some circles on a scatter plot via:

```
<Grid>
    <oxy:PlotView x:Name="PlotView" Title="{Binding Title}" >
        <oxy:PlotView.Axes>
            <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" Minimum="-30" Maximum="30" IsAxisVisible="False" IsZoomEnabled="False" IsPanEnabled="False" />
            <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left" Minimum="0" Maximum="35" IsAxisVisible="False" IsZoomEnabled="False" IsPanEnabled="False"/>
        </oxy:PlotView.Axes>
        <oxy:PlotView.Series>
            <oxy:ScatterSeries Height="100" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" MarkerType="Circle" />
        </oxy:PlotView.Series>
    </oxy:PlotView>
</Grid>
```

I cannot figure out how to enable some sort of click handler to have an event fired when a user clicks on a `DataPoint`.

Examaple:

User clicks `DataPoint` at (X, Y) = (0, 5), I would like to fire an event so I can handle the click of that point.

Is this possible with OxyPlot? I am currently investigating the `Tracker` to see if its possible that route, but starting to run out of ideas.

Comment: have you tried `plotView.MouseDown` event?

Comment: I have. I am able to get the x and y position of the mouse, but it is not relative to the actual plot.

Comment: I have not tried this, but `InverseTransform` is used to translate mouse coordinates to plot coordinates.

Comment: kenny: can you add that as an Answer so I can mark it as the correct one? Looks like that's what I needed to move forward!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`PlotView` has defined mouse events, from which you can get the mouse coordinates, and `InverseTransform` is used to translate mouse coordinates to plot coordinates.

Example:

```
var model = new PlotModel { Title = "Test Mouse Events" };

var s1 = new LineSeries();
model.Series.Add(s1);

double x;

s1.MouseDown += (s, e) =>
{
    x = (s as LineSeries).InverseTransform(e.Position).X;
};
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but can you provide an example of this solution? I'm struggling on get it to work.

Comment: No event fires for me using this.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get the accepted answer to work. The `MouseDown` handler wouldn't receive events when the plot was left-clicked. It would, however, receive events for right-clicks and double-clicks.

My workaround is to listen for `PreviewMouseDown` on the `PlotView`.

Comment: `MouseDown` doesn't receive events because you likely have a custom series and don't override `TrackerHitResult GetNearestPoint(ScreenPoint point, bool interpolate)`. I had the same issue, but once I added an override for that method to just return the InverseTransform - everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

The series' `MouseDown` events are deprecated since v4.0. What you can do now is add a `TrackerManipulator` and catch the mouse down events there:

```cs
public class DoSomethingWithPointTrackerManipulator : OxyPlot.TrackerManipulator
{
  public DoSomethingWithPointTrackerManipulator (IPlotView plotView) : base(plotView)
  {
    Snap = true;
    PointsOnly = true;
  }

  public override void Started(OxyMouseEventArgs e)
  {
    base.Started(e);
    DoSomethingWithPoint(e);
  }

  private void DoSomethingWithPoint(OxyMouseEventArgs e)
  {
    var series = PlotView.ActualModel.GetSeriesFromPoint(e.Position) as ScatterSeries; // Or other type of series...
    if (series == null) return;

    var nearestPoint = series.GetNearestPoint(e.Position, false); // Possible set interpolate parameter to true.
    if (nearestPoint == null) return;

    var dataPoint = nearestPoint.DataPoint;
    var scatterPoint = series.Points.FirstOrDefault(x => Equals(x.X, dataPoint.X) && Equals(x.Y, dataPoint.Y));

  // Do whatever you want with the point.
  }

  public override void Completed(OxyMouseEventArgs e)
  {
    // Do nothing to avoid closing the tracker.
  }
}
```

Then add this to your `PlotController`:

```cs
var mouseButton = OxyMouseButton.Left // Or whatever button you want the event to be fired with.
yourPlotController.BindMouseDown(mouseButton, 
    new DelegatePlotCommand<OxyMouseDownEventArgs>((view, controller, args) =>
      controller.AddMouseManipulator(view, new DoSomethingWithPointTrackerManipulator (view), args)));
```