# OxyPlot get clicked Position in PlotView/PlotModel

Tags: c#, wpf, plot, oxyplot

I'm trying to get the clicked position in my `PlotView` or `PlotModel`. But I just get some window-screen points not concerning any values in my `PlotModel`.

The question [OxyPlot get clicked point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001215/oxyplot-get-clicked-point) is about clicking on `LineSeries`, not in any poisition of my plot.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `InverseTransformation` with your `MouseEvent.Position` and your axis.

```
private void MyPlotModel_MouseDown(object sender, OxyMouseDownEventArgs ex)
{
    OxyPlot.ElementCollection<OxyPlot.Axes.Axis> axisList = MyPlotModel.Axes;

    Axis xAxis = axisList.FirstOrDefault(ax => ax.Position == AxisPosition.Bottom);
    Axis yAxis = axisList.FirstOrDefault(ax => ax.Position == AxisPosition.Left);

    DataPoint dataPointp = OxyPlot.Axes.Axis.InverseTransform(ex.Position, xAxis, yAxis);

    // Do stuff with dataPointp ... 
}
```